# QFileDialog under OSX dumps many errors to console

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

Trying to use QFileDialog under OSX 10.6.8, Qt 4.7:

```
QFileDialog *dialog = new QFileDialog(0,tr("Load Band Recordings"),qbh,tr("Wave Files (*.wav)"));
dialog->setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);

if (dialog->exec())
{
QStringList fileNames;
    fileNames = dialog->selectedFiles();
    qs = fileNames[0];
}
else
{
    return(0);
}
```

It works, but many errors are dumped to the console:

```
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
2012-05-13 11:03:41.445 SdrDx[18982:903] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x31197, window:0xffffffff
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: doClip: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
2012-05-13 11:03:41.533 SdrDx[18982:903] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x31197, window:0xffffffff
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: doClip: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
2012-05-13 11:03:41.576 SdrDx[18982:903] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x31197, window:0xffffffff
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 machine-mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: doClip: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
2012-05-13 11:03:41.616 SdrDx[18982:903] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x31197, window:0xffffffff
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: doClip: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID -1
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSDeviceCreate: Invalid window
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: Failed to create window context device
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGWindowContextCreate: failed to create context delegate.
2012-05-13 11:03:41.638 SdrDx[18982:903] _initWithWindowNumber: error creating graphics ctxt object for ctxt:0x31197, window:0xffffffff
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextAddRect: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: doClip: invalid context 0x0
Sun May 13 11:03:41 -mac-pro.local SdrDx[18982] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

The docs say provide the parent widget; doesn't seem to matter.

Anyone have any idea how to CORRECTLY use the Qt 4.7 QFileDialog class under OSX so that it doesn't vomit errors to the console?

Btw, both the static and the constructed versions of the file and directory dialogs do this. I've asked over on the Qt forums, but received no answer. Hoping someone here has figured it out.

Comment: Why aren't you passing a parent widget? (And did you try doing that?)

Comment: Why are you not returning in the body of the if statement? Currently you are only doing it in the else statement.

Comment: You are using Qt 4.7 Carbon, don't you?

Comment: Mat, yes, I tried passing a parent widget, no change -- same error dump to console. Anthony: because with successful execution of the dialog, there is more to do. If the dialog fails, I need to exit the procedure -- I can't proceed without the filename. Kamil, I'm using Qt 4.7 and 4.8 (two different projects) and I get the same results in both of them.